# Can't stop {me/my} loving myself

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 1. You can't stop me loving myself.
> 2. You can't stop my loving myself.

Which one is more grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

They both are correct. "You can't stop me (doing what?) loving myself." You can't stop (what?) my loving myself." But I'd go for the first: You can't stop me loving myself. It may be just my personal preference.

Some more examples like this:

> You can't stop me dancing. ([source](https://open.spotify.com/track/1lR2cYBQ9mkV7IbyNiBLMm))
>
> You can't stop me dreaming. ([source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007IUE08S))

By the way, it's also fine to say "You can't stop me **from** dreaming." And, sure enough, "you can't stop me from loving myself" is correct too.

As for "stop my doing something", it also works:

> I can't stop my loving you. ([source](https://genius.com/Buck-owens-i-cant-stop-my-loving-you-lyrics))
>
> Nothing can stop my loving you. ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3Nv2LPyneo))